# Normalized Ricci flow for a 2-dimensional, closed Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was looking at Chow and Knopf's book, *The Ricci Flow: An Introduction*, and noticed that the normalized Ricci flow is defined as

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g = -2\text{Ric} + \frac{2}{n}rg \tag{1}
$$
where
$$
r = \frac{\int_M S \, d\mu}{\int_M d\mu},
$$
and $S$ is the scalar curvature.

Later on, the normalized Ricci flow for a 2-dimensional, closed Riemannian manifold is given as
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}g = (r-S)g \tag{2}\\
$$

I am now wondering how one goes from (1) to (2). Given the form of the traceless Ricci tensor
$$
\overset{\circ}{\text{Ric}} = \text{Ric}-\frac{1}{n}Sg,
$$
I am led to wonder if the manifold being closed somehow results in $\overset{\circ}{\text{Ric}}=0$ so that for the $n=2$ case, $\text{Ric}=\frac{1}{2}Sg$, which in turn gives (2).

Is this how (2) is obtained? If not, could someone please point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: In two dimensions the Ricci tensor (and even the full Riemann tensor) has only one independent component, see for example [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_curvature_tensor#Special_cases).

Comment: Ah, that is much simpler than I expected. Thanks for pointing that out! @pregunton